# Need help deleting loaded array and clearing it from count

Tags: c++, arrays, count

I have been messing around with some code. I've really just mashed things together and exploring ways to get what I want out of it.

Right now something that has been bothering me is that when I try to delete a user it leaves the user blank instead of deleting it completely. I would rather it delete/remove the line completely and adjust the count without removing any other user data.

EDIT:
The problem is that after I delete a user. When I list every user it displays a blank User: pass: etc instead of not listing those to begin with. if I were to save the file it would have 5 empty spaces. I'd rather it remove those lines completely as if they were never there to begin with.

This is how I load the code:

```
int Loadpdata()
{

ifstream fp_in;

if(count > 0)
{
    cout << "pdata already Loaded.\nTotal of " << count << " users loaded." << endl;

    return 0;

}


fp_in.open("p.data"); //Open user file

if(fp_in == NULL)
{
    cout << "Could not open user file, exiting." << endl;
}

while(!fp_in.eof()) { //While there is something to read

    getline(fp_in,userd[count]);
    getline(fp_in,passd[count]);  //Read a line from the file
    getline(fp_in,aged[count]);  //Read a line from the file
    getline(fp_in,locationd[count]);  //Read a line from the file
    getline(fp_in,emaild[count]);  //Read a line from the file
    getline(fp_in,mid[count]);  //Read a line from the file


    cout << "User: " << userd[count] << " Loaded Successfully." << endl;
    userstotal++;
    count++;
}
fp_in.close(); //Done with the user file

cout << "Total Users Loaded: " << count << endl;

if(!count > 0)
{
    cout << "Userlist is empty, exiting" << endl;
    return -2;
}
return 0;

}
```

Now this is how I delete the user:

```
int Deletedata()
{
char user[80];
int logged_in=0;
while(!logged_in) { //Force user to login. Give a quit option if you'd like
cout << "Enter user name: ";
cin >> user;
int found = 0;
for(int x=0;x<count && !found;x++) { //For each user/password pair..
  if(userd[x].compare(user) == 0) { //Matched the username
    found = 1;
      logged_in = 1;
      userd[x].clear();
      passd[x].clear();
      aged[x].clear();
      locationd[x].clear();
      emaild[x].clear();
      mid[x].clear();
  }
}
if(!found) {
  cout << "Invalid username!" << endl;
}
}
//Once we're done with that loop, they logged in successfully.
cout << "Deleted " << user << " Successfully." << endl;
return 0;


}
```

The more I think about this the more I realize I may have to scrap it and come up with a new format.

Comment: So what EXACTLY is the problem?  You don't specify.  Is something not working correctly?  If you want a code review, go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want the data file updated you will need to write out all the records - omitting any deleted records of course.

Comment: Are you trying to serialise and deserialise instances of a class from a file? Use a library for that, like boost.serialization. This kind of task can be very error-prone if you roll your own.

Comment: I just edited the post, my bad. The problem is that after i delete a user. when i list every user it displays a blank User: pass: etc instead of not listing those to begin with. if I were to save the file it would have 5 empty spaces. I'd rather it remove those lines completely as if they were never there to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just remove one entry and not touch any of the other entries, you'll need to use a node-based container, e.g., a `std::list<T>` or a `std::map<K, V>` (the latter would match your needs of locating an object by a key anyway).

That said, if you want to stick with an array and fill the gap, you have two principle options:

1. If you don't care about the order of the objects, you could just `std::swap()` the to-be-removed object with the last copy and then remove the newly last element.
2. If the order matters to you, you'll need to move all the objects after the gap forward. The easiest way to do that is probably to use `std::remove_if()`.

BTW, trying to read a file and checking `in.eof()` does **not** work reliable. In particular, when there are no more objects `eof()` may or may not be `true` and you don't check *after* reading whether the read was successful. Also note that `eof()` may never become `true`, e.g., if the file contains a format error and gets into fail state. You should read you data using something like

```
while (std::getline(in, userd[count])
    && std::getline(in, passd[count])
    // ...
    && std::getline(in, mid)) {
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't heard of map before and that works. Only did a bit with it so far, I have run into one issue though. I use extern map<int, string> userdb; and that is causing an issue. I used it for string before to load it and it worked fine. Any ideas? That code to use instead of eof helped with a save problem i was having. Thank you sir.

Comment: nvm i got the map to work in other files with the extern, was only missing the #include <map> and namespace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing the element at position x, use erase on the vector (must be std::vector, and not C-array)